# SQLite how to get result of conditional column update?

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I'm building a barebones E-commerce site in ASP.NET Core with SQLite for my repository.  I keep track of the stock of a product in my store with what I'm calling the 'ProductInventory' table which holds has an integer column called 'Stock'.  Now I never want stock to be negative so even though I have checks in software prior to an update query it's still possible that two users could be checking out at roughly the same time resulting two update queries that could result in a negative.  So I figure I use a case statement to determine how much to subtract.  Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
UPDATE [ProductInventory] 
SET [Stock] = CASE WHEN [Stock] >= X Then [Stock] - X Else [Stock] = 0
END WHERE [ID] = 1
```

In the example above X is a placeholder for the amount I wish to deduct from the Stock column.

What I can't figure out is how can I get the information back as to how much was deducted?  My guess is I'm using the wrong SQL query here or I have the wrong idea entirely, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree, boss.  You'd be much better off using database transactions.  In a transaction, you can group multiple SQL statements; all the statements are executed together, and they all succeed together or else are rolled back.  Here's some C# pseudocode:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
{
  conn.Open();
  using SQLiteTransaction dbTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    if (StockIsAvailable())
    {
      DecreaseStock();
      IncreaseCashBalance();
    }
    dbTransaction.Commit();
  }
}
```

In my example, `StockIsAvailable()`, `DecreaseStock()`, and `IncreaseCashBalance()` are functions that execute SQL statements on the database.  My point is that if you were to use transactions, then if another e-commerce transaction were to happen while you were in the middle of the first one, then the second e-commerce transaction would have to wait until the first database transaction was committed.  It would be impossible for the database to be left in an invalid state, such as a negative quantity of stock.

Good luck with your e-commerce site!

Comment: Thanks I'll definately give it a try!